# Automatic database update with DbUp in multi application environment

Tags: database-schema, database-concurrency, dbup

I have multiple desktop apps that can run DbUp at startup. And how to handle this situation if couple apps run DbUp at the same time?

I have to have automatic solution for that because there are plenty clients and DB update cannot be run by the DBA. It must be work automatically after the app update (actually it is also automatic).
DB update could be executed during the application update. But also it doesn't solve the concurrency problem because app update also could happen simultaneously. DbUp doesn't have any lock mechanism instead of transaction. I've added some lock table and added script to update value in it at every update script begin. But there is a problem that script continue to run after other DbUp instance finishes the job.

It would work if the lock table update run before schemaversion reading. Then after the lock table release it would read schemaversion table and could then realize that there are all updates already executed.

Application .Net Core based and DB is MySql.